# Is it possible to program from shell (vim + tmux) and host an ipython server for the matplitlib graphs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, ipython

I currently host an ipython (or jupyter) notebook on an AWS server. I write my programs and get the outputs (matplotlib graphs) from the notebook, but I find it quite uncomfortable. The graphs are great, but I'd much prefer to program from ssh, wich is what I usually do when I dont need graphs. I'd still like to be able to see the graphs though, which is not possible from console.

So, is it possible to start an IPython session and send some code to it from the shell (the serious programming), and some code from the notebook web client (the matplotlib code)?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am also looking for a similar thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is X11 forwarding an option? You can see matplotlib graphs this way.

```
ssh -X user@host
```

Comment: I think what he is asking is whether its possible to write the code in vim, then send it to the ipython terminal, and have the resulting graph display in the notebookformat. The reason is when you are doing heavy coding, its a pain to leave the vim session over and over again to the jupyter notebook to run the code. However, I am not sure this is possible ATM.